# Change another div's background hovering multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, animation

Developing a menu, I've encountered some troubles in something quite easy (apparently not for me).

[EXPLANATION IMAGE http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/7060/hoverdivexpl.jpg](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/7060/hoverdivexpl.jpg)

Backgrounds / menu buttons, are ALL images.

I already tried to solve that with the other StackOverflow (and others) users suggestions but can't figure out how to proceed. Once it works hovering the button but doesn't switch back to the div's bg; then works but nothing fades.

Having a base knowledge into web developing/jQuery, I'm stuck.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with the code you have.

Comment: What is your current code that does not switch back?

Comment: Felix, i would like to read some code

Comment: Maybe a good idea to add an example piece of code. Would be even better if you added it to jsfiddle.net. This way the person who answers can exactly see what you tried and thus what you did wrong. Now it seems more like a 'give me code plx, i'm to lazy' question.

Comment: @Umesh: Don't tell me, tell Manuel ;)

Comment: Can't handle what I did right now.
I've made something similar but it's just a turnaround (badly "written" and can't be a solution for sure).

There is no "fading effect" at the moment (I'll give a look to Willem Mulder's script), but at first will understand something more about the basics of that "call-div-action-on-hover".

http://jsfiddle.net/doppelgaenger/zUu7z/5/

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For both the buttons something like

```
$(selector1).hover(
    // Function to call when mouse enters element
    function() { 
        // Animate to set new background in 100 milliseconds
        $(this).animate({'background': 'A'},100); 
        $(bigdivselector).animate({'background': 'A'},100); 
    }, 
    // Function to call when mouse leaves element
    function() { 
        $(this).animate({'background': 'defaultBG'},100); 
        $(bigdivselector).animate({'background': 'defaultBG'},100); 
    }, 
);
```

Where obviously you'll have to substitute the selectors and backgrounds with the proper values.